# BuddyPress - access variable outside the while loop

Tags: php, buddypress

I'm trying to make men/women filter on buddypres members loop page, so condition is: if user is man no profiles are visible, but women can see only men's profiles and I  need to save this variable for each member from xprofile field:

```
$profile_gender = xprofile_get_field_data('10', bp_get_member_user_id() );
```

but this variable needs to go outside while loop somehow.

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
//figure out if the logged-in user is male or female
$sex = xprofile_get_field_data( 10, bp_loggedin_user_id() );
?>
<!-- condition -->
<?php if (($profile_gender=='Man') && ($sex=='Woman') || ( is_super_admin())) { ?>

   <?php while ( bp_members()) : bp_the_member();
   // here's the variable for checking the gender of displayed profile
   $profile_gender = xprofile_get_field_data('10', bp_get_member_user_id() ); 
   ?>
   <!-- second condition for displaying only men -->
   <?php if ($profile_gender=='Man') { ?>

      <!--members loop here-->

      <?php endwhile; ?>

   <?php } ?>

<!-- some message-->
<?php } else { echo 'some message'} ?>
```

Comment: Hmm, I've read your question multiple times and am still not sure what you are trying to ask.  You say the variable needs to go outside the loop, and you put it outside the loop.  Where is your problem?

Comment: Well if I put this before while loop I can not get values from 'xprofile_get_field_data' for each member, that's the problem.

Comment: to be more specific 
$profile_gender = xprofile_get_field_data('10', bp_get_member_user_id() );

works only inside the while loop, and I need the "if condition" to be before the while loop

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you mean.  You want to get the gender for each member which you are looping through with `<?php while ( bp_members()) : bp_the_member(); ?>`   Is there a reason you can't get the gender of each member inside the while loop?  You say it needs to go outside while loop somehow, why?  Looking at your code it kind of looks like the outer `if` statement should be inside the loop, and the outer `if` should just check that `$sex` is female, but perhaps I am misunderstanding you intentions.

Comment: $sex checks the gender of the visitor, and it works OK. As you can see from the condition I also need to show only men's profiles if the visitor is woman

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. Here is my understanding of what you want to do, correct me if I am wrong.

A visitor has a gender, which is stored in the `$sex` variable.

If that visitor is a woman, we want to show them men's profiles.

If the visitor is a man, don't show them any profiles.

The gender of the profiles is stored in `$profile_gender`, and the code for displaying the profile is in the while loop.

Comment: Th reason I am confused is because I see no reason why your `if` condition is checking the profile gender.  Furthermore, to accomplish what I think you want you would need to reset `$profile_gender` for each member inside the while loop so as to filter out women.

Comment: Actually i need you to thank you for giving me an idea despite misunderstanding :) I will update the code now

Comment: Code is updated and working, thx again

Comment: you should probably mark this question as closed.